# monit: Consolidated dashboard for monit running on multiple machines

Tags: monit

I have monit setup on multiple machines. For Example: x.example.com:2812, y.example.com:2812 and z.example.com:2812. Is there a way so that we can see all these dashboards consolidated at one place let's say at web location consolidated.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

Buy [M/Monit](https://mmonit.com) (multi-Monit).

It's [inexpensive](https://mmonit.com) and will give you a nice dashboard view of your systems.
M/Monit easy to install and gives you the ability to drill-down into systems issues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is the company behind monit sells a product called m/monit

https://mmonit.com/

You need to buy a license to use it after a free trail